# Is there a way to get collective permission for multiple Data points from Healthkit

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I am creating an application which needs to fetch heartRate, restingHeartRate, walkingHeartRateAverage, HeartRateVariabilitySDNN data from HealthKit.

Also I want to fetch user's body measurement data. i.e body mass index, body temperature, height, waist circumference, weight.

To get read permission I need to get separate permission for each data type:

```
let healthKitTypesToRead: Set<HKObjectType> = [
    HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!,
    HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRateVariabilitySDNN)!,
    HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .restingHeartRate)!,
    HKObjectType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: .walkingHeartRateAverage)!,
    HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass)!,
    HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMassIndex)!,
    HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyTemperature)!,
    HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .height)!,
    HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .waistCircumference)!,
    HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .weight)!,
]
```

It shows multiple toggles on the permission screen, which I feel will be too much for the user to give individual permission to each. (in case they don't want to give all permissions.)

Is there a way to group the permissions or are there some dataTypes which if given permission will let us collect other dataTypes as well.

Initially I thought permission to heartRate meant I could fetch restingHeartRate, walkingHeartRateAverage, etc. But they all need their separate permissions.

Comment: Health data is the most sensitive and therefore the most heavily protected data on the user's phone. Your app must ask for and receive permission for each data type that it wants to access. This is by design. Apple wants the user to be very clear about what data they are providing access to.

Comment: Makes sense. But is there a way to group various healthKit dataTypes and give a common toggle to similar permissions. That would let user give individual permissions but will be more convenient.

Comment: No, the user must individually grant access to all of the items you are requesting access to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each HealthKit type must be authorized independently:

> To help protect the user’s privacy, HealthKit requires **fine-grained authorization**. You must request permission to both read and share **each data type** used by your app before you attempt to access or save the data.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/authorizing_access_to_health_data

Apple foresaw the difficulty of asking for many HealthKit types at once, and suggests to ask permission for different permission types at various times in your app rather than all at once:

> However, you don’t need to request permission for all data types at once. Instead, it may make more sense to wait until you need to access the data before asking for permission.

The HealthHit permission dialog also does have a single button that allows the user to enable all requested types:

> Turn All Categories On

[image: Turn All Categories On]